# Data from UniData to SQL Server 2005/above through SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis, unidata

We are doing a feasibility on what we're going to propose as a solution to a client who wants to migrate to a .NET based solution. Part of the data resides in UniData. What is required can be achieve using the following tool:

http://www.welland.com/export.html

The above product ETLs data from UniData to SQL Server.

As a first step, we want to be sure that there are no hitches in getting the data through SSIS from UniData to SQL Server.

Since we don't have an environment to test this we have to check mostly on the net. But most of the discussions regarding UniDate and SSIS don't look like the problem got solved. The main problem seems to be that people aren't able to get hold of a proper ODBC driver. If the data is converted into XML, then it looks like it's working fine.

Has anyone done this and know that this can go through without any problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot say I've done it, but [Rocket Software](http://rs.com/u2) has 2-user license versions of UniData available for [download](http://www.rocketsoftware.com/u2/downloads/), so at least you would have a system to test on.

Answer (score 0):

We are actually working on this process now -- Unidata to SQL through SSIS.  We worked with Rocket Software to get the OLE DB working... ODBC was never fast enough and before there was not OLE DB... Now there is.  You have to do some work on the UNIDATA side once the OLE DB is install but that is an answer for another day.  So far we have no issues except the work to get it setup.